# always get the wrong conditions, when placing the cursor

Tags: android, string

I have a code to take the value from the table, but when I place it in a condition, I will get the wrong answer

```
jenis_absen = cursor.getString(9);
System.out.println("jenis absen >>" + jenis_absen);
System.out.println("cursor >>" + cursor.getString(9));
if (jenis_absen == "1"){
     System.out.println(">>>>> TRUE");
 }
 else{
      System.out.println(">>> FALSE");
 }
```

[image]

**this is the output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jenis_absen = cursor.getString(9);
System.out.println("jenis absen >>" + jenis_absen);
System.out.println("cursor >>" + cursor.getString(9));
if (jenis_absen.equals("1")){
     System.out.println(">>>>> TRUE");
 }
 else{
      System.out.println(">>> FALSE");
 }
```

== compares the reference of the String, if both the String references are same then it will be true but .equals() compares the value inside String.

Comment: thank you very much, sorry if the question is still trivial,